# React - sending an email using wp_mail

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, wordpress

I am attempting to create a contact form in React which I would like to use to send an email through my Wordpress installation. Normally if I were making an AJAX call, I would have to pass the name of my submit function in as an action like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'admin-ajax.php',
    data: { action: 'send_form' }
}).done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

However, since I am not using jQuery in my React app, I am making the call using `fetch`:

```
const res = await fetch('admin-ajax.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.values),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});
```

My question is, how can I pass along the action, `send_form` in my React call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append to your `body` parameter:

`body: JSON.stringify({...this.state.values, 'action': 'send_form'})`